# Common Lisp Loop accumulator: minimize into multiple-value-bind?

Tags: loops, common-lisp, sbcl

```
(defvar x '((5 . a) (3 . b) (1 . c) (9 . d)))
> X
(loop for i in x minimize (car i))
> 1
```

What I would like, is to get C instead of 1. I tried using values, because it will still use the first return value for minimization, but I don't know if there is a way to use multiple-value-bind in this context?

```
(loop for i in x
      minimize (values (car i) (cdr i)) into ans
      finally (return ans))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am afraid you would have to write the code yourself:

```
(let ((best ()))
  (dolist (pair x (cdr best))
    (when (or (null best) (< (car x) (car best)))
      (setq best pair))))
```

This scans the list just once.

This however, calls the key (`car`) multiple times (as mentioned in a comment).

This can be optimized:

```
(defun find-best (list &key (key #'identity) (test #'<))
  (when list
    (let* ((best (first list))
           (best-key (funcall key best)))
      (dolist (o (rest list) best)
        (let ((k (funcall key o)))
          (when (funcall test k best-key)
            (setq best o best-key k)))))))
```

Comment: It doesn't matter so much when the key is just `car`, but this calls the key function (in this case, `car`) multiple times on the best value.  If the key has any side effects, or is expensive to compute, it might be worthwhile to minimize this.  (Of course, not all CL functions do this.  E.g., the docs for `sort` say "There is no guarantee on the number of times the key will be called.")

Answer (score 4):

```
(defvar x '((5 . a) (3 . b) (1 . c) (9 . d)))

(loop for (num . sym) in x
      with min-num = nil
      with min-sym = nil
      do (when (or (null min-num)
                   (< num min-num))
           (setf min-num num
                 min-sym sym))
      finally (return (values min-sym min-num)))
;=> C, 1

;; see. http://common-lisp.net/project/iterate/doc/Finders.html#Finders
(ql:quickload :iterate)
(use-package :iterate)
(iter (for (num . sym) in x)
      (finding sym minimizing num))
;=> C
```

Comment: Thanks anon for pointing out `iterate` package; I haven't used it before, seems pretty neat -- another tool in the toolbox :)

Answer (score 1):

```
CL-USER 15 > (defparameter *x* '((5 . a) (3 . b) (1 . c) (2 . d) (9 . e)))
*X*

CL-USER 16 > (loop with (min-n . min-v) = (first *x*)
                   for (n . v) in (rest *x*)
                   if (< n min-n) do (setf min-n n min-v v)
                   finally (return min-v))
C
```

as a function:

```
(defun minimize (list &key (pred #'<) (key #'identity))
  "returns values: the minimum value and if there was one"
  (if (null list)
      (values nil nil)
    (values (loop with min-e = (first list)
                  with min-v = (funcall key min-e)
                  initially (pop list)
                  for e in list 
                  for v = (funcall key e)
                  if (funcall pred v min-v) do (setf min-e e min-v v)
                  finally (return min-e))
            t)))


CL-USER 35 > (minimize '((5 . a) (3 . b) (1 . c) (2 . d) (9 . e)) :key #'car)
(1 . C)
T
```

Comment: ; simplify and fix typo cadr/cdar


`(loop


     with x = '((5 . a) (3 . b) (1 . c) (9 . d))


     with (min-n . min-v) = (first x)


     for (n . v) in (rest x)


     if (< n min-n) do (setf min-v v)


     finally (return min-v))`

Comment: Oops, change `(setf min-v v)` to `(setf min-n n min-v v)`

Comment: @devon: right, I had that already in the function. Changed in the LOOP also.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a minimization problem, you should only have to walk the list once. You can do this directly with `loop`, `dotimes`, or some of the other iteration constructs fairly easily.  If you want a more functional approach, you might use something like this:

```
(defun keyed-predicate (predicate key)
  (lambda (x y)
    (if (funcall predicate
                 (funcall key x)
                 (funcall key y))
        x
        y)))

(cdr (reduce (keyed-predicate '< 'car) '((5 . a) (3 . b) (1 . c) (9 . d))))
;=> C
```

The problem with this, though, is that it calls the key function multiple times on elements that are at some point the "current best value".  This happens in [sds's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20252156/1281433), too (`car` is called on `best` multiple times)`, though it's not an issue with`car`, since`car` doesn't have any side effects. E.g.,

```
(cdr (reduce (keyed-predicate '< (lambda (x) 
                                   (format t "visiting ~a~%" x)
                                   (car x)))
             '((5 . a) (3 . b) (1 . c) (9 . d))))
; visiting (3 . B)
; visiting (3 . B) ; repeat
; visiting (1 . C)
; visiting (1 . C) ; repeat
; visiting (9 . D)
;=> C
```

It would be good to ensure that the key function is called just once on each element, and that's easier to in an iterative implementation. E.g.,

```
(defun optimum (predicate list &key key)
  (flet ((key (x) 
           (if (null key) x
               (funcall key x))))
    (if (endp list)
        (funcall predicate)
        (let* ((best (first list))
               (best-key (key best)))
          (dolist (item (rest list) best)
            (let ((item-key (key item)))
              (when (funcall predicate item-key best-key)
                (setf best item
                      best-key item-key))))))))

(cdr (optimum '< '((5 . a) (3 . b) (1 . c) (9 . d)) :key 'car))
;=> C
```

In this, the key is called just once per item:

```
(cdr (optimum '< '((5 . a) (3 . b) (1 . c) (9 . d)) 
              :key (lambda (x) 
                     (format t "visiting ~a~%" x)
                     (car x))))
; visiting (5 . A)
; visiting (3 . B)
; visiting (1 . C)
; visiting (9 . D)
;=> C
```